# Using jQuery to load page into a div element and remove current loaded page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to load content/pages dynamically without having to leave the page, or, the page changing. Assume the following:

I have four pages: `index.php, about.php, contact.php, products.php` and when a visitor visits the website, by entering "http://mysite.com" they are greeted with the "index.php" page.

If they click onto a link, let's say "about" then the "index" page is removed and the contents of "about.php" is displayed inside the div `content-loaded` I have tried the following:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#content-loaded").load("index.php");

   $('.about').click(function() {

       $("#content-loaded").load("about.php");
   });

   //....
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
   <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
   <a href="#" class="about">About</a>
</div>

  <div id="content-loaded">

  </div>
```

But this does not work. It displays both the index page AND the about page. Could anyone suggest any improvements/answers or a more elegant way to structure this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cleaning the previous content. See if this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#content-loaded").load("index.php");

   $('.about').click(function(evt) {
       $("#content-loaded").empty();
       $("#content-loaded").load("about.php");
       evt.preventDefault();
   });

   //....
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it clears it but then the "index.php" page just comes back

Comment: @user1326876 try 
$('.about').click(function(evt) {
       $("#content-loaded").empty();
       $("#content-loaded").load("about.php");
       evt.preventDefault();
   });

Comment: Thank you! This now works =) I don't suppose you could recommend a way of allowing for say, if someone entered `http://mysite.com/about.php` into their browser, then it would show the page as if they were clicking on the link? So at the moment, it just shows the text and not the actual layout of the site.. If this makes sense?

Comment: My suggestion to you is not to use JS for that. Just add a variable to your index.php page. For instance, http://mysite.com/index.php?page=about
That is common practice and is much easier to do.
All you have to do is to check your `$_GET['page']` variable in the beginning of your index.php file and then add the specific content. 
you can insert the content from others php files (about, contact, ...) directly in your index.php by doing using `include`.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery 1.9.1 and the following source code, worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#content-loaded").load("index.php");

   $('.about').click(function() {
       $("#content-loaded").empty();
       $("#content-loaded").load("about.php");
   });

   $('.home').click(function() {
       $("#content-loaded").empty();
       $("#content-loaded").load("index.php");
   });

   //....
});
</script>
```